# Using TinyRadius in Spring Boot Service failing to start tomcat

Tags: spring-boot, web-services, microservices, radius, tinyradius

I am trying to create a spring boot service using TinyRadius library. Consumers will call this service passing UserName & Password and I need to connect to the radius server for authentication. I am using IntelliJ for development. I have included below TinyRadius gradle dependency in gradle file

> compile(group: 'org.tinyradius', name: 'tinyradius', version: '1.1.0')

but when I start my application inside IntelliJ it throws below error. Removing the above dependency and commenting out Radius Server code Tomcat inside IntelliJ starts but as soon as I have tinyradius dependency it fails to start.

> [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat
> initialized with port(s): 8081 (http) [           main]
> o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat] [
> main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet
> engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.38] [           main]
> org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase   : A child container failed
> during start
>
> java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException:
> org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component
> [NonLoginAuthenticator[StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost].TomcatEmbeddedContext[]]]
> at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)  at
> java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192)  at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:916)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:843)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1384)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1374)
> at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)     at
> org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
> at
> java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:134)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:909)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:421)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:930)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
> at org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat.start(Tomcat.java:486)    at
> org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.initialize(TomcatWebServer.java:123)
> at
> org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.(TomcatWebServer.java:104)
> at
> org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.getTomcatWebServer(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:437)
> at
> org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.getWebServer(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:191)
> at
> org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.createWebServer(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:178)
> at
> org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:158)
> at
> org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:545)
> at
> org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:143)
> at
> org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:758)
> at
> org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:750)
> at
> org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397)
> at
> org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315)
> at
> org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1237)
> at
> org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226)
> Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start
> component
> [NonLoginAuthenticator[StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost].TomcatEmbeddedContext[]]]
> at
> org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.handleSubClassException(LifecycleBase.java:440)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:198)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.startInternal(StandardPipeline.java:176)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5056)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1384)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1374)
> at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)     at
> org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
> at
> java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:134)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:909)
> ... 30 common frames omitted Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
> javax.servlet.ServletContext.getVirtualServerName()Ljava/lang/String;
> at
> org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.startInternal(AuthenticatorBase.java:1342)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
> ... 40 common frames omitted

Here is a sample code that I have in the controller so far. I am just trying to see if the server starts up and then can proceed. Any help is appreciated on how to implement this inside spring boot webservice

```
import org.tinyradius.packet.AccessRequest;
import org.tinyradius.packet.RadiusPacket;
import org.tinyradius.util.RadiusClient;

public void connect() throws Exception{

        RadiusClient rc = new RadiusClient("radiusserver", "secretcode");
        rc.setAuthPort(9999);
        rc.setRetryCount(4);
        rc.setSocketTimeout(30000);

        AccessRequest ar = new AccessRequest("name", "pwd");
        RadiusPacket response = rc.authenticate(ar);
    }
```